# html5 capture the screen

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using HTML5/Canvas/Javascript to take screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots)

Is there a way for a browser to take a global screenshot ? I mean, the entire screen, including what is not in the browser.

I kown that I may sound a little bit silly by asking this.

Comment: Absolutely not with HTML5, but you can probably do it using a plugin like Flash.

Comment: Not possible, also, duplicate. ^

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The proposed duplicate is only concerned with capturing a web page, though, rather than the entire screen. The Google+ functionality referenced in the question only captures the page, and the accepted answer only explains how to capture a page. The question does not ask (and the accepted answer does not explain) whether capturing the entire screen is possible or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is [experimental support for full-screen capture](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pluginfree-Screen-Sharing/) in Chrome's `getUserMedia` WebRTC function, using a `{chromeMediaSource: 'screen'}` parameter. The functionality currently requires explicit activation by an option in `chrome://flags`, and (like all WebRTC capture mechanisms) requires explicit consent from the user when the function is called.

Other than that experimental option in Chrome, is not possible using pure JavaScript, but you could probably do it using a plugin like Flash, or an ActiveX control.

If you only want to capture a web page (rather than the whole screen), see [Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots).

Comment: Ok. Take a screenshot of the browser is not that big deal. Well actually it would be, but Eric Bidleman explained how to do it here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/streaming/screenshare/

I think that I'm going to try a mix between flash and html :)

Comment: Hm.. still not supported by firefox.